# Material UI DataGrid Pro renderCell with asynchronous data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's DataGrid Pro. I have a column for a user's avatar and I need to asynchronously get the image. I want to show a skeleton URL image while the image is loading that then gets swapped out for the actual url. This is my current approach:

```
{
      field: "avatar",
      headerName: "",
      headerClassName: "tableHeader",
      width: 80,
      cellClassName: "profilePictureCell",
      renderCell: async (params: GridRenderCellParams<CounselorDashboardStudentRow>) => {
        const url = await getDownloadURL(
          ref(storage, params.value)
        );
        return (
          <Avatar
            alt={params.row.firstName + " " + params.row.lastName}
            src={url ? url : ""}
            sx={{ width: 50, height: 50, mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
          />
        );
      },
    },
```

When I run this, I get an error stating the renderCell is trying to return a Promise instead of a JSX element.

I'm not sure I'm using the best approach here and could use help figuring out how to dynamically render async content in a specific column.

I don't want to asynchronously load the entire row since none of the other data should have to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

The `renderCell` typings seems to accept an asynchronous callback but doesn't actually await the promise and calls the function synchronously.

The solution I used when I encountered this was to create a separate component to handle the loading data, and then pass that component to `renderCell`.

An example for your case:

```js
export const AvatarCell = ({
  params,
}: GridRenderCellParams<CounselorDashboardStudentRow>) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const url = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, params.value));
        setUrl(url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting URL", error);
      }
    };

    getUrl();
  }, [params.value]);

  return (
    <Avatar
      alt={`${params.row.firstName} ${params.row.lastName}`}
      src={url || ""}
      sx={{ width: 50, height: 50, mt: 1, mb: 1 }}
    />
  );
};
```

Then pass through to `renderCell` synchronously:

```js
renderCell: (params) => <AvatarCell params={params} />
```